# Proxy-Authorization Header not working in HttpWebRequest, in case of Rest Request to a URL

Tags: vb.net, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am using [HttpWebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8) for fetching data from Rest API.
I have proxy applied on my system and I need to authorize with Proxy Server in order to fetch data from Rest API.

For Authorization, I am using [Proxy-Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) header with value as "Basic base64_credentials".

But even after sending these credentials, I am not able to authorize with Proxy Server.

If I hit same Rest API from Postman by giving Proxy-Authorization header it works perfectly.

Here is my code :

```
        Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)

        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjE6UGFzc3dvcmQx")

        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET"

        myHttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate Or DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.None

        Dim myHttpWebResponse = GetresponseForRequest(myHttpWebRequest)
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

I have not touched HttpWebRequest.Proxy settings.

Comment: Does postman send a UserAgent?

Comment: Yes, postman sends User Agent.

Comment: Have you tried putting the same value in myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent

Comment: No, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: One more thing that I noted is that when I hit http api, then it works fine but for https it doesn't work.